# How to specify username password for ftp

Tags: ftp

```
ftp ftp://bapte:b2p7Ua2@ftp.backupte4.rsyncbackup.info
```

And I got

```
ftp: ftp://bapte:b2p7Ua2@ftp.backupte4.rsyncbackup.info: Name or service not known
```

I tried a bunch of different things. I looked at manual. No luck

I tried

```
ftp -user username password ftp.backupte4.rsyncbackup.info
```

as said in manual

```
ftp: u: unknown option
```

All I need is a sample that works.

The manual said

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ftp.htm

user user-name [password ] [account ]
    Identify yourself to the remote FTP server. If the password is not specified and the server requires it, ftp will prompt the user for it (after disabling local echo). If an account field is not specified, and the FTP server requires it, the user will be prompted for it. If an account field is specified, an account command will be relayed to the remote server after the login sequence is completed if the remote server did not require it for logging in. Unless ftp is invoked with auto-login disabled, this process is done automatically on initial connection to the FTP server.

So what exactly I should put?

Comment: You could install `ncftp`, a much better ftp client with a long history. `ftp` is not very secure (clear text name and passwords) and is generally deprecated in favor of the `ssh` suite of utilities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can't exactly do it with a command line option, but what you can do is redirect stdin like so:

```
$ ftp -n ftp.backupte4.rsyncbackup.info << EOF
> quote USER bapte
> quote PASS b2p7Ua2
> put somefile  <-- this is the command you want to execute
> quit
> EOF
```

or you can put it in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ftp -n ftp.backupte4.rsyncbackup.info << EOF
quote USER bapte
quote PASS b2p7Ua2
put somefile
quit
EOF
```

Finally you could use `lftp`:

```
lftp -u bapte,b2p7Ua2 -e "your command;quit" ftp.backupte4.rsyncbackup.info
```

http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html

Comment: If you get a certificate error you might need to edit or create this file: `~/.lftprc` and add the line `set ssl:verify-certificate false`.

Comment: `ftp -n` didn't work for me. I have to use `ftp -in` to get it to work. Also, I am not sure what the purpose of `quote` is. I just use `USER <username> <password>`